# Genexus 17, generador .net, Web, para windows se no se puede generar los objetos

Tags: genexus

Quiero crear aplicacion win y web, dentro la version genexus 17, pero nome deja para cuando eligo windows.

Necesito instalar algun producto adicional? o simplemente no lo soporta.

el error que me da es:
error: Environment 'win' has at least generator 'Default (Java)' that targets an unsupported platform.
Failed: Build With This Only

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Como estas Hernan?

El generador Win está descontinuado desde GeneXus v15.

Saludos!